# Circle: snap to grid

Tags: inkscape

I have two simple paths:

[image]

As you can see, the circle is not quite matching to the corners of the 2nd shape.

Closer look:

[image]

I converted everything into paths, but I can't realise how can I make that small move on the circle upwards to match these 3 lines?

So to illustrate: how can I move the circle up to make the red dot go to the green one:

[image]

I don't want to distort the circle at all, just want to move it upwards.

Comment: By the way you have succeded to ask 2 xy questions in a row. Demonstrating why xy questions are bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a grid for this. It can all be done with snapping and a couple of modifier keys. This seems like a lot to remember, but it's not that hard once you get used to Inkscape's snapping options which are very powerful.

1. Set up the snapping controls as shown below. The main three to remember here are snap to paths, snap to cusp nodes, and snap to rotation centres. The magnet icons are just to toggle each of the different groups of snapping controls - just make sure these ones shown are all engaged.

[image]

2. Using the Ellipse Tool <kbd>E</kbd> draw a circle/ellipse, and deselect it by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Note: If you need a circle hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as you click and drag to constrain the aspect ratio to 1:1.
3. Choose the Rectangle tool <kbd>R</kbd> and draw a rectangle by hovering over the centre of the circle. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click and drag to make a rectangle which is perfectly centred inside the circle.
4. Using the Select Tool <kbd>S</kbd>, hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click and drag the rectangle up until the corner intersects with the path of the circle. This modifier key constrains the move vertically or horizontally
5. Convert the rectangle to paths using *Path > Object to Path*, or use the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
6. Choose the Edit Paths by Nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd> and engage the Show Transform handles option

[image]

7. Click and drag around the two lower nodes of the rectangle to select them
8. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click and drag to scale the transform handles symmetrically.

An example

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You obviously know the size of a good circle, but cannot get it to go through 2 wanted points A and B (see NOTE1).

One possibility is to find the right centerpoint for the circle. If you have point snaps ON (including crossing and center snaps), but the grid snap is turned OFF, the circle snaps easily to the wanted center:

[image]

The right size circle (red) is moved to point A. An auxiliary line (orange) is drawn from A to B and rotated 90 degrees with the infoline rotate button.

The red circle is duplicated and the duplicate (green) is moved to the crossing of the orange line and the red circle.

**NOTE1**: I guess points A and B are a part of an already existing drawing and cannot be moved.

Comment: Thanks, I can use this, although a bit different: I don't need to snap the center, but the arc itself. I.e. move the green circle to cross the red at the exactly same point as the orange line. But with snapping tools it's easy now, so the trick here really is to just turn off the grid, and draw some helper lines. Alternatively I can union the circle and the line and it will create extra nodes at the crossing which then can be snapped to anything :)

Comment: There exists no other possible centerpoints for the circle than the crossings of the red circle and the orange line if the circle size was given beforehand and the circle must go through given points A and B. If it happens that you do not need the actual circle, but only an arc between A and B you can draw it with the Bezier tool in Spiro mode. Click on A, on an intermediate arc point and on B. Right click to finish.